# =Counta recognise 0.5 conditional formatting as half

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've conditionally formatted a row so that when you put H or S or P in it changes colour.
At the end of the row I have done the =Counta formula so that I can get the total.

The problem is I also have H-0.5,S-0.5 and P-0.5 (Half day). Is there a way to make =counta at recognise this?

The total is linked to another spreadsheet and if some of the employee's only have 14.5 days remaining of holiday it will say 15 for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count "H", "S" or "P" as 1 but any with 0.5 as 0.5 then try this formula, assuming data in A2:Z2

`=COUNTA(A2:Z2)-COUNTIF(A2:Z2,"*0.5")/2`

Comment: Do you mean =COUNTA(A2:Z2)-(COUNTIF(A2:Z2,"*0.5")/2)

Comment: @Oliver Lockett - No, your formula does the same as mine, adding those parentheses doesn't change the outcome

Answer (score 1):

Lets say all your H, S, P and H-0.5 S-0.5 and P-0.5 are in column A. Try this

```
=sum(countif(A:A,{"H","S","P"})+(sum(countif(A:A,{"H-0.5","S-0.5","P-0.5"})/2))
```

This will first count all the instances where column a contains an h, s or a p, and then count all the other 0.5 instances - but divides the second group by two, to get your half values

Comment: barry's formula is more efficient, use that